# Where and how do I add JavaScript code and CSS code in PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I have a PHP file I called it for the test index1.php
In the file I have this code now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    lang="en"
    xml:lang="en"
><head>

<meta
    http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="text/html; charset=utf-8"
/>

<meta
    http-equiv="Content-Language"
    content="en"
/>

<meta
    name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width; height=device-height; initial-scale=1.0"
/>

<link
    type="text/css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="screen.css"
    media="screen,projection,tv"
/>

<title>
    change picture
</title>

</head><body>

<div id="slideCounter"></div>
<div id="slideShow">
<?php

$allowed_types = ['png','jpg','jpeg','gif'];
$imageDir = 'files/radar-simulation-files';
/*
    Assumes this .php is being run from the http root on the same
    domain as the desired image files.
*/

$handle = opendir($imageDir);
while (($imgPath = readdir($handle)) !== false) if (
    in_array(
        strtolower(pathinfo($imgPath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)),
        $allowed_types
    )) echo '
    <img src="', $imageDir, '/', $imagePath, '" alt="slide" />';
closedir($handle);

?>
<!-- #slideShow --></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="slideShow.js"></script>

</body></html>
```

Now I have to use with this code also JavaScript code and I don't know where to add this code ?

```
(function(d) {

    // user defines

    var
        swapHours = 0,
        swapMinutes = 0,
        swapSeconds = 5,
        swapTotal = (swapHours * 60 + swapMinutes) * 60 + swapSeconds,
        loopSlideShow = true;

    // some handy helper functions

    function classExists(e, className) {
        return RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)').test(e.className);
    }

    function classAdd(e, className) {
        if (classExists(e, className) return false;
        e.className += (e.className ? ' ' : '') + className;
        return true;
    }

    function classRemove(e, className) {
        if (!classExists(e, className)) return false;
        e.className = e.className.replace(
            new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + n + '(\\s|$)'), ' '
        ) . replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
        return true;
    }

    function textReplace(e, newtext) {
        if (d.innerText) e.innerText = newText;
            else e.textContent = newText;
    }

    function nodeFirst(e) {
        e = e.firstChild;
        while (e && e.nodeType != 1) e = e.nextSibling;
        return e;
    }

    function nodeLast(e) {
        e = e.lastChild;
        while (e && e.nodeType != 1) e = e.prevSibling;
        return e;
    }

    function nodeNext(e) {
        while (e) if ((e = e.nextSibling).nodeType == 1) return e;
        return null;
    }

    function nodePrev(e) {
        while (e) if ((e = e.prevSibling).nodeType == 1) return e;
        return null;
    }

    // slideShow setup

    var
        slideShow = d.getElementById('slideShow'),
        slideCounter = d.getElementById('slideCounter'),
        firstSlide = nodeFirst(slideShow),
        lastSlide = nodeLast(slideShow),
        currentSlide = firstSlide,
        swapCounter;

    classAdd(slideShow, 'ss_scripted');
    classAdd(currentSlide, 'ss_show');

    // slideShow functions

    function showCounter() {
        textReplace(slideCounter, 
            Math.floor(swapCounter / 3600) + ':' +
            (Math.floor(swapCounter / 60) % 60) + ':' +
            swapCounter % 60
        );
    }

    function resetCounter() {
        swapCounter = swapTotal;
        showCounter();
    }

    function makeSlide(newSlide) {
        classRemove(currentSlide, 'ss_show);
        currentSlide = newSlide;
        classAdd(currentSlide, 'ss_show');
    }

    function nextSlide() { 
        resetCounter();
        var newSlide = nodeNext(currentSlide);
        if (newSlide) makeSlide(newSlide);
            else if (loopSlideShow) makeSlide(firstSlide);
    }

    function prevSlide() {
        resetCounter();
        var newSlide = nodePrev(currentSlide);
        if (newSlide) makeSlide(newSlide);
            else if (loopSlideShow) makeSlide(lastSlide);
    }

    function slideUpdate() {
        if (swapCounter--) showCounter(); else nextSlide();
    }

    function startSlideShow() {
        resetCounter();
        setInterval(slideUpdate, 1000);
    }

    // wait for onload to actually start the countdown 

    if (window.eventListener) w.addEventListener('load', startSlideShow, false);
        else w.addEventListener('onload', startSlideShow);

})(document);
```

I tried to add this code in between this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="slideShow.js"></script>
```

Between the script tags.

1. Is that correct to add this code between the script tags ?
2. I'm getting 3 errors on this code:

On the line: if (classExists(e, className) return false; Expected ) but found return

On the line: classRemove(currentSlide, 'ss_show); missing close quote

On the line: currentSlide = newSlide; Expected , but not found

And last where do I add the CSS code ?

Comment: you are correct to put it between the `script` tags but you must remove the `src` attribute, or else the browser will ignore what is inside the tags and will try, instead, to download the file specified in `src`

Comment: It seems like you should do some studying about the work you're doing. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp

Comment: See http://quirksmode.org/js/placejs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your first error, `if (classExists(e, className) return false;`, it should be `if (classExists(e, className))`. You are missing a right parenthesis.

In regards to your second error, you are missing the close quote as the error states. It should be `classRemove(currentSlide, 'ss_show');`.

With the last error, the code is expecting a comma instead of a semi-colon at the end of the statement.

Put the code between the `script` tag and remove the `src` tag. You can have more than one `script` tag as well.